# Node.js - Calling asynchronous functions whenever a toggle is changed

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, amazon-sns

In my website, I have a toggle button that determines whether or not a given user will receive messages from a given source. Whenever this toggle is changed, an asynchronous function needs to be called. However, if the toggle is changed, and then it is quickly changed again, my program must wait for the previous asynchronous call to finish. Here are my two functions that call the asynchronous functions

```
_enable() {
    let params = determineSubscriptionParams(this.endpoint, this.level);

    SNS_CLIENT.subscribe(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        else {
            // do stuff here
        }
    });
}

_disable() {
    let params = {
        SubscriptionArn: this.subscriptionArn
    }

    SNS_CLIENT.unsubscribe(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        else {
            // do stuff here
        }
    });
}
```

Both of these functions are members of a class and the subscribe and unsubscribe functions are the asynchronous calls

Comment: Then you'd need cancellable requests. Or disable the toggle until the first request has completed.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a lock for critical sections of code. If you don't want to implement your own, you could use [async-lock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-lock) to accomplish this.

This is will make the second request made in quick succession unable to enter the critical part of the code before the first request has released it.